# Distortion Node Black Area

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to render beyond the black/transparent area created by the Distortion Node added in compositing? A simple crop or perhaps an overscan might fix this, but hoping to have it just render. What causes the black area to begin with?

[image]

Comment: If this is the _Lens Distortion_ node you're talking about, if the distortion bulges the image by pulling it in, the black comes simply from the fact that there is nothing outside the image that could fill the gaps that result when the image borders are pulled in. Remember this is a post effect, there is nothing rendered outside the border. However, the _Lens Distortion_ has a "Fit" option that scales the image up until no black is left.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, that did it. I don't know how I missed it, so simple. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to render it distorted in the first place, you can go to the camera properties, choose _Lens_ > _Type_ > _Panoramic_ and _Panorama Type_ > _Fisheye Equisolid_. Play around with values for _Lens_ (0.01 to 15) and _Field of View_ (10° to 360°) to get the look you want. Note that the result is only visible in _Rendered View_, not in _Solid View_ or _Material Preview_. With these settings you will also get a transparent background if the _Lens_ and/or _FoV_ are set to low values, but if you don't want that you can change the values until you got rid of the transparency.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Great info, thank you! So the distortion node is a post effect, whereas what you've just described must be more of an actual lens rendering (in-camera) effect?

Comment: Yes, the distortion node is a post-effect to simulate choosing a fisheye lens etc., but you can do this in direct rendering if you setup the camera accordingly. A real fisheye lens usually captures more content, wider images. The post effect has to deal with what is there and can't "add" more environment.